# React and Socket.io | useState generates new socket connection onChange in input

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, onchange

I'm using React and Socket.io but I have an issue. Each character I write in the input field, a new socket id is created and I do not want that to happen. When I remove the setUsername(e.target.value) in the onChange method no socket are created. Here is my code:

**Server Side:**

```
const express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    http = require('http').createServer(app),
    PORT = 5000,
    io = require('socket.io')(http);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('New client with id: ' + socket.id);

    socket.on('disconnect', () => console.log('Disconnected'));
});

http.listen(PORT, (req, res) => console.log('Server has started on port: ' + PORT));
```

**Client Side:**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import io from 'socket.io-client';
import 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css';
import M from "materialize-css";

function App() {

  const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000');
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    M.AutoInit();
    //eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  const onChange = e => {
    setUsername(e.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form onClick={e => handleSubmit(e)}>
        <input id="name" placeholder="Username..." onChange={e => onChange(e)} required />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[Here is the output for each character I write (I typed 'username')](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mh8wH.png)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

Every time you update the state, the App component is rendering so the variables are being initialized again:

```
const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000');
```

Move the initialization into into `useEffect()` and declare the socket variable outside `App.js`, or keep it inside App.js but use a `useRef()`;

```
useEffect(() => {
    M.AutoInit();

    async function connect () {
           socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000');
        }
    connect();

  }, []);
```

Full code:

```
let socket = null;
function App() {

  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    M.AutoInit();
    async function connect () {
               socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000');
            }
        connect();
  }, []);

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  const onChange = e => {
    setUsername(e.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form onClick={e => handleSubmit(e)}>
        <input id="name" placeholder="Username..." onChange={e => onChange(e)} required />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

Right, you're creating a new instance on every re-render because you're defining `socket` in the top-level scope of App.

You already have a `useEffect` hook in place, so try initiating the connection within that hook instead. Since you've passed an empty array as a second argument to the hook, the code will only be executed once (at the time the component is mounted).